# Cannot install libpng12 on debian 10 (buster) which is required for making stata 14 works

Tags: debian

I am a newbie but I have tried to use some distros like ubuntu, linuxmint even arch linux and its derivatives but I found my liking with debian.  I just have one issue as to my computer needs using debian 10 and that is how to install libpng12 which is required for stata 14 to work.  I have tried a lot of solutions proposed on many forums but up to now without luck in installing libpng12 on my debian buster installation.  I only need a simple step by step 'procedure' on how to do this successfully so I can go ahead with data analysis for my research using stata 14.

Comment: Do not use Ubuntu's .DEB files to "update" a Debian installation. Similar comments apply to all non-Debian distros. You are storing up trouble if you should succeed in doing so. You can find libpng12 on **Debian 9 [Jessie]**. Presumably, its an indication that Strata 14 is not particularly recent?

Comment: @JeremyBoden Debian 9 is actually Stretch. 8 is Jessie.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake.

Comment: You can use `libpng12-0`from Debian Jessie https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libpng12-0

Comment: @KnudLarsen It's not a good idea to install packages from another distribution due to dependency/compatibility issues. Doing so runs the risk of ruining the system.

Comment: Nasir Riley : Old / absent / missing packages with no conflicts / no dependencies are recommended all the time, fresh example https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344045/e-unable-to-locate-package-libcr-dev by N0rbert.

Answer (score 1):

Debian 10 has `libpng16` in its repos which is more recent. Stata 14 was released about 6 years ago where the `libpng` version was 12.

The `libpng` versions are usually backwards compatible so installing 16 on your system may work but if it doesn't, the other option that you have is to compile it from source and add it to your environment.

You can get the source code here: https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/tree/libpng12

Comment: The point of the soname bump from .12 to .16 is that there are breaking changes between the versions... It might work, but there’s no guarantee.

Comment: @StephenKitt True. That's why I also recommended building it from source due to the chance that it may not work.